# Javascript, writing dynamic content to textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, onclick

I am programming a blog in php, for the record I've just started out but Im doing pretty good with this PHP but Javascript I don't really understand.

On my blog I would like people to comment and discuss.

What I want:

Every comment has an id that is displayed.

I want to click on it and then the Javascript should place it in the textarea for leaving comments.

Thats all.

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but I don't think you need to reinvent the wheel. It's fun to do, but really hard to continue past a certain point. There are *tons* of CMS systems. I recommend WordPress, personally.

Comment: You're not bursting my bubble dude :) I've worked years with Wordpress (working on themes) but I am looking for a new kind of job so I am learning php by giving myself a project to work on. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer uses jQuery.)

```
// getting a reference to the TEXTAREA element
var $ta = $("#new_comment textarea");

$(".comment").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).find(".text").text(); // depends of the structure
    $ta.val(text);
});
```

---

```
<div class="comment">
    <p class="author"> Peter </p>
    <p class="text"> Good article! </p>
</div>
```